# How to rotate SpriteNode with touch?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode, swift-playground

How can I rotate a SpriteKit node on a fixed point with touch. So it turns as the user drags his finger. I also want to be able to get the rpm. (This question was asked before but I want to know how to do it using SpriteKit)
Swift 3 Playgrounds

I've got this so far which works but sometimes i get an error for var deltaAngle  = angle - startingAngle!   ERROR - "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value"

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
var startingAngle:CGFloat?
var startingTime:TimeInterval?


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let wheel = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "IMG_6797.PNG" )

    wheel.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)

    wheel.name = "wheel"
    wheel.setScale(0.5)
    wheel.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: wheel.size.width/2)
    // Change this property as needed (increase it to slow faster)
    wheel.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 4
    wheel.physicsBody?.pinned = true
    wheel.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    addChild(wheel)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in:self)
        let node = atPoint(location)
        if node.name == "wheel" {
            let dx = location.x - node.position.x
            let dy = location.y - node.position.y
            // Store angle and current time
            startingAngle = atan2(dy, dx)
            startingTime = touch.timestamp
            node.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = 0
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.location(in:self)
        let node = atPoint(location)
        if node.name == "wheel" {
            let dx = location.x - node.position.x
            let dy = location.y - node.position.y


            let angle = atan2(dy, dx)
            // Calculate angular velocity; handle wrap at pi/-pi
            var deltaAngle = angle - startingAngle!
            if abs(deltaAngle) > CGFloat.pi {
                if (deltaAngle > 0) {
                    deltaAngle = deltaAngle - CGFloat.pi * 2
                }
                else {
                    deltaAngle = deltaAngle + CGFloat.pi * 2
                }
            }
            let dt = CGFloat(touch.timestamp - startingTime!)
            let velocity = deltaAngle / dt

            node.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = velocity

            startingAngle = angle
            startingTime = touch.timestamp
        }
    }
}



override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    startingAngle = nil
    startingTime = nil
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far? ;)

Comment: I was initially going to use UIKit (UiGestureRecogniser) but I used too little of SpriteKit in my wwdc playground and need to add more. I'm new to SpriteKit so not sure how to do it @Whirlwind

Comment: You should use the the touchesBegan and touchesMoved overrides to get the touch location, then calculate the tangent angle at which your node should rotate to.  For starters, make sure your node graphic asset is oriented to the right, otherwise your angles will be off.  Start there and come back with some code if you still need help.

Comment: I've managed to make it work but i get an error something (edited question) @TheValyreanGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means exactly what it says.  Most likely, "wheel" is not getting touched in touchesBegan, but then registering in touchesMoved, causing startingAngle to not be set to anything and nil.

Since you probably don't want your wheel to spin if the user didn't start touching on the wheel, I would add a guard in touchedMoved

```
...
let angle = atan2(dy, dx)

guard startingAngle != nil else {return} //Exit the function if starting angle was never set

var deltaAngle = angle - startingAngle!
...
```

Comment: The code spins the wheel if the user flicks it, how can you get it to turn as the user drags his finger?